# Extended Cauchy Theorem (possibly for Cyclic group only)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Cauhy Theorem works for prime divisors.

Does any divisor correspond to a subgroup?

If the group is cyclic do every divisor correspond to a subgroup?

Comment: Divisors of the order do not imply existence of a corresponding subgroup. For example, there is no example of a subgroup of order 6 in $A_4$.

Answer (score 2):

No, if $G$ is a finite group and $d$ is a divisor of its order, then there does not always exists $H\leqslant G$ of order $d$. For a counterexample, consider $G=A_4$ and $d=6$, if such a $H$ exists, it has index $2$ and thus must contains all squares of $A_4$. However, by inspection, there is $9$ squares in $A_4$.

Nevertheless, if $G$ is cyclic, then such a $H$ exists and is unique.

You may be interested in [Sylow's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) which give sufficient conditions for such a subgroup to exist.